# Add a comments for tables columns in a physical data diagram

Tags: powerdesigner

I can see my column comments through double-clicking on table and selecting a Columns tab.
But when I choose Display Preferenses-> Table-> Advanced...-> Columns-> List Columns [select] - I cant't find this attribute "Comment" there.

Is it possible to add the attribute ColumnComment from the model to be shown in Physical Diagram, and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add it directly because they are rtf texts not simple strings,
so this kind of attributes are not listed.

**But there is a workaround!**
You can add an custom calculated attribute to columns which will return the converted string from description (comment)

First of all you have to add an Extension to your PDM model,
go to *Model->Extensions* and add a new one,
then follow these instructions:

Open properties of newly created extension
Select *Profile* and right click, select *Add Metaclasses*, check *Column* and press OK.
Select *Column* and right click, select *New->Extended Attribute*
Give it a name
Select data type *string*
Check *Computed*
Select *Read only (Get method)*
Select *Get Method Script* tab
Replace

```
%Get% = ""
```

with

```
%Get% = Rtf2Ascii (obj.Description)
```

Press `OK` to close the extension properties window.
Press `OK` to close the extension list window.

Now open *Tools->Display Preferences->Table->Advanced->Columns*
Click *Select* for columns list
Check your new attribute and press `OK` three times to return to diagram

[image]
Enjoy

Comment: My database is mysql , Replace %Get% = ""  with  %Get% = Rtf2Ascii (obj.Comment)  is work for me .

Comment: Good idea.
You could create the extension through `Tools > Extensions > All Model Types..`, to make it a global reusable one. And attach the extended attribute to NamedObject (in Add Metaclass, go to PdCommon tab, and modify the filter to select `Show Abstract Modeling Metaclasses`) to make it available on all objects having a description.

Answer (score 1):

I put  `%Get% = obj.Comment` instead of `%Get% = ""` - and it works, 
but `%Get% = Rtf2Ascii (obj.Description)`  - doesn't

(PD 16.6.)