# showing description in powerdesigner

Tags: character-encoding, powerdesigner, physical-design

I have a physical data model in powerdesigner and want to show description for every fact and dimension and their attributes in the model. Following the [powerdesigner add comment column in physical data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40283974/add-a-comments-for-tables-columns-in-a-physical-data-diagram)
answer, I have a column shows the description but the problem is it shows ? for each character.

The descriptions in my databases are in non-English language and I want to show the original description in powerdesigner. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which language? not that it matters that much, but the solution might be different for Arabic/Hungarian, than for Chinese/Japanese...

Comment: Strange... It worked for me. The name Rtf2Ascii is a little misleading... [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdz8I.png)  Which version of PowerDesigner are you using?

Comment: @pascal it is Arabic and the version is 16.6.

Comment: @pascal by the way I update the model by reverse engineering not by LDM.

Comment: Does the font used to display the symbols support Arabic?

Comment: @pascal yes it does.